# WEBPACK ISSUE and NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am working on the frontend part of my project using Redux. It was all good then all all of a sudden these errors showed up. I have 23 errors like this.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

I created a webpack.config.js file and did this. But the errors aren't going away. I'm new to this and just trying out new stuff.

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { url: require.resolve("url/") }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    // fallback: { stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify") }
    fallback: { "stream": false }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { "path": false }
  }
}
```

Then i npm install those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all the configurations under a single module.exports object, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            url: require.resolve("url/"),
            path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
            zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I don't why it is not working for me